# How long can the SpaceX Starlink satellites survive before they deorbit?

Tags: falcon-9, orbit, low-earth-orbit, starlink, deorbit

Like most Low Earth Orbits (LEOs), the Starlink satellites will eventually have their orbits decay and burn up in the Earth's atmosphere. How long, on average, will this take? I am assuming that there are zero factors other than gravity and aerodrag. For these purposes, the satelittes are at 550 km. So, how long can the SpaceX Starlink satellites survive before they deorbit?

Comment: 550km as most Starlink satellites are launched to.

Comment: I had always assumed that mass and cross sectional area would also be factors in the rate of orbital decay, in addition to altitude and solar activity. Is this not true?

Comment: Mass would not for sure. Cross sectional area matters a small amount. @MikeH

Comment: @MikeH mass and cross-sectional area both matter (and are frequently considered together as "[ballistic coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_coefficient)."  It's trivially provable that for a given drag force (determined by the shape and area of the body), drag acceleration (i.e. decay) scales with the inverse of mass.  See e.g. the simplified model at [the Wikipedia page for Orbital decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_decay)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Around 5 Years**

Starlink satellites are launched into orbits between 335 and 354 miles above the Earth.  SpaceX had originally planned to fly some of their constellation at 800 miles,  but petitioned the FCC to change the architecture such that all their satellites fly below 380 miles.  This was requested specifically to reduce the time it would take for a dead satellite to de-orbit.

[SpaceFlight Now - FCC clears SpaceX to fly satellites at lower altitudes](https://spaceflightnow.com/2021/04/29/spacex-launches-60-more-starlink-spacecraft-fcc-clears-spacex-to-fly-satellites-at-lower-altitudes/)

SpaceX publishes a graph showing expected decay times as a function of altitude:

[image: SpaceX graph of decay time vs altitude]

The reason I said 'around' 5 years is that decay times can be affected by solar storms and other factors, and the satellites will be at slightly different orbits.  But that wouldn't affect decay times at that altitude very much.

Comment: What is wrong with the satellite having a longer decay time? A longer decay time just gives SpaceX more time to use the satellite before they have to replace it. Actually, wouldn't a longer decay time be a good thing, not a bad one? @Dan Hanson

Comment: Space Junk is a problem.  The satellites are going to have a fixed lifespan,  and some are going to fail early.  You don't want thousands of dead satellites floating around in orbit.   The satellites won't deorbit so long as they are functional, as they have ion thrusters for maintaining their orbit.    But once they die,  you want them out of orbit as quickly as possible.

Comment: Isn't space really, really, really big though. So maybe if one tiny, tiny, tiny part is taken up by a satellite, big deal. Move your thing a few feet over and you'll be fine. @Dan Hanson

Comment: Satellites are zipping around the Earth at very high speed.  Satellites do collide.  For example,  in 2009 an Iridium satellite collided with a defunct Russian satellite.  Two collisions happened in 2013, and another in 2019.  The big problem here is that the collision between two satellites creates thousands of little tiny satellites,  increasing collision risks exponentially.

Comment: While space is big, LEO is not so big and is already crowded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137350/discussion-between-starship-is-go-for-launch-and-fyrepenguin).

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something? Each satellite, with the overall program cost for development, manufacture, and launch, is only going to work for 5 years??

Comment: @BruceWayne It seems so - the idea being in 5 years they will be sufficiently obsolete to be replaced by a new, upgraded batch anyway. They do have krypton hall effect thrusters on board, for station-keeping, but it appears they aren't intended to extend their lifetime past the 5 years.

Comment: @BruceWayne they'll de-orbit 5 years after failing or running out of station keeping prop.  Although since not being controllable makes them a hazard, SpaceX will probably deliberately deorbit them before they run dry.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that the 2 biggest costs are launch costs and development costs. You don't lose the development when the satellite de-orbits, and SpaceX is betting that Starship will make launch costs 5-10x cheaper within 5 years

Comment: That graph surprised me a little bit. Is it specific to the Starlink satellite design? It seems like there needs to be a third axis that accounts for the connection to mass and surface area.

Comment: The other thing to add is that while existing communications satellites might stay in operation for 10+ years, they make most of their money in the first few when they're the fastest things in space.  After faster rivals launch their returns become much lower, but due to the cost of replacement they keep running them for much longer anyway. OTOH SpaceX's construction and launch costs are far lower than anyone elses; if Starship delivers they might end up scrapping all the v1.x satellites being launched by Falcon early in favor of the much larger and more capable Starship only v2 models.

Comment: @SF. Do you have a citation for the claim the thrusters aren’t for extending life beyond 5 years? What is station keeping if not preventing orbit degradation?

Comment: @Tim [link](https://subspace.com/resources/spacex-is-giving-the-internet-lift-with-starlink), and the thrusters are to keep the constellation structured, with even coverage, instead of a random chaotic swarm - keeping the satellites spread evenly in their orbits - plus make sure the lifetime is 5 years, regardless of solar weather bloating our atmosphere and accelerating orbital decay.

Comment: @DanielWagner the graph is from SpaceX, so yes, it's tailored to the mass and profile of Starlink.

Comment: I said to continue this discussion in chat not for it be completely ingored.

Comment: @BruceWayne: The prototypes, version 0.9, version 1.0, and even the version 1.5 which is currently being launched are already obsolete. The only reason they are still launching v1.5 is because v2 can only be (economically) launched on Starship. As soon as Starship is operational-ish (at least operational enough for Starlink), literally every single Starlink satellite ever launched and even the ones that will be launched in the near future, is obsolete. Why would they want to run obsolete tech? Note that even the very first orbital flight test will already attempt to deploy Starlink 2s, so …

Comment: … Starship becoming operational-ish for Starlink might come sooner than you think.

Comment: @ Dan Hanson: THANK YOU! I kept searching for the simple answer; could find nothing but calculus [which subject I actually scored an "A" in, in college]. Thanks for letting me be lazy, and rely on your calcs.

Comment: @FrankLaSush - You are invited to this chat.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142745/newbies-space-survival